# Internal SQL Server Error when referencing a named instance of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to script some inserts from a source database to a target database, using linked servers.  For the first time we are using a second named instance of SQL, and it is giving me an "Internal SQL Server Error" when I run the following code.  If I remove the brackets around the named instance, I no longer get the Internal SQL Server Error, but I do get a "Incorrect syntax near '\'." error.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
declare @listname as varchar(80) 
declare @sourcedb as sysname
declare @targetdb as sysname

set @listname = 'List(r) Stuff - Planning'

set @sourcedb = '[server1.domain.com\server1sql2005].database.dbo.'
set @targetdb = 'server2.database.dbo.'


print @listname

exec ('if not exists (select * from ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader where listname = ''' + @listname + ''') 
begin
    insert ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader (listname, userdefinedname1, userdefinedname2, userdefinedname3, siterecnum, dolplistnum, listdate, regdate, customlist, footer) 
        select 
            mlmh.listname, 
            mlmh.userdefinedname1, 
            mlmh.userdefinedname2, 
            mlmh.userdefinedname3, 
            mlmh.siterecnum, 
            mlmh.dolplistnum, 
            mlmh.listdate, 
            mlmh.regdate, 
            mlmh.customlist, 
            mlmh.footer
        from ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatchingheader mlmh 
        where mlmh.listname = ''' + @listname + ''' 
    end
    else
    begin
        update ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader set  
            listname = mlmh.listname, 
            userdefinedname1 = mlmh.userdefinedname1, 
            userdefinedname2 = mlmh.userdefinedname2, 
            userdefinedname3 = mlmh.userdefinedname3, 
            siterecnum = mlmh.siterecnum, 
            dolplistnum = mlmh.dolplistnum, 
            listdate = mlmh.listdate, 
            regdate = mlmh.regdate, 
            customlist = mlmh.customlist,
            footer = mlmh.footer 
        from ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader lmh 
        inner join ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatchingheader mlmh on lmh.listname = mlmh.listname 
        where mlmh.listname = ''' + @listname + ''' 
    end
    ')

exec ('
    delete ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching 
    from ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching lm 
    inner join ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader lmh on lm.listrecnum = lmh.listrecnum 
    where lmh.listname = ''' + @listname + ''' 
    ')

exec ('
    delete ' + @targetdb + 'listitemcass 
    from ' + @targetdb + 'listitemcass lic 
    where not exists (select * from ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching where listitemrecnum = lic.listitemrecnum) 
    ')

exec ('
    delete ' + @targetdb + 'listitemingreds 
    from ' + @targetdb + 'listitemingreds lii 
    where not exists (select * from ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching where listitemrecnum = lii.listitemrecnum) 
    ')

exec ('
    insert ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching (listrecnum, cas, ingredient, userdefineddata1, userdefineddata2, userdefineddata3) 
    select 
        lmh.listrecnum, 
        mlm.cas, 
        mlm.ingredient, 
        mlm.userdefineddata1, 
        mlm.userdefineddata2, 
        mlm.userdefineddata3 
    from ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatching mlm 
    inner join ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatchingheader mlmh on mlm.listrecnum = mlmh.listrecnum and mlmh.listname = ''' + @listname + ''' 
    inner join ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader lmh on mlmh.listname = lmh.listname 
    ')

exec ('
    insert ' + @targetdb + 'listitemcass (listitemrecnum, cas, abstrue) 
    select 
        lm.listitemrecnum, 
        mlic.cas, 
        mlic.abstrue 
    from ' + @sourcedb + 'listitemcass mlic 
    inner join ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatching mlm on mlic.listitemrecnum = mlm.listitemrecnum 
    inner join ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatchingheader mlmh on mlm.listrecnum = mlmh.listrecnum and mlmh.listname = ''' + @listname + ''' 
    inner join ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader lmh on mlmh.listname = lmh.listname 
    inner join ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching lm on lmh.listrecnum = lm.listrecnum and mlm.cas = lm.cas and mlm.ingredient = lm.ingredient and mlm.userdefineddata1 = lm.userdefineddata1 and mlm.userdefineddata2 = lm.userdefineddata2 and mlm.userdefineddata3 = lm.userdefineddata3 
    ')

exec ('
    insert ' + @targetdb + 'listitemingreds (listitemrecnum, ingredienttext, abstrue) 
    select 
        lm.listitemrecnum, 
        mlii.ingredienttext, 
        mlii.abstrue 
    from ' + @sourcedb + 'listitemingreds mlii 
    inner join ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatching mlm on mlii.listitemrecnum = mlm.listitemrecnum 
    inner join ' + @sourcedb + 'listmatchingheader mlmh on mlm.listrecnum = mlmh.listrecnum and mlmh.listname = ''' + @listname + ''' 
    inner join ' + @targetdb + 'listmatchingheader lmh on mlmh.listname = lmh.listname 
    inner join ' + @targetdb + 'listmatching lm on lmh.listrecnum = lm.listrecnum and mlm.cas = lm.cas and mlm.ingredient = lm.ingredient and mlm.userdefineddata1 = lm.userdefineddata1 and mlm.userdefineddata2 = lm.userdefineddata2 and mlm.userdefineddata3 = lm.userdefineddata3')
```

Comment: Will you provide the entire text of the "internal sql server error" error?

Comment: so you get an internal error from 3 SETs and a PRINT? Aren't you missing something in this code sample?

Comment: Can you show us the entire code set that is failing

Comment: Entire code set is below

Comment: Complete error message - 

List(r) Stuff - Planning
Msg 8624, Level 16, State 123, Line 21
Internal SQL Server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was doing something stupid, in that I was actually running the query from a SQL2000 instance, and my source db was on a SQL2005 instance, and apparently that is not good.  When I ran my query from the 2005 instance, it ran just fine.  Thanks for all the input, and sorry for the run around...

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the name is correctly written in the @SourceDB and @TargetDB variables.

To get a list of the names registered as linked servers, use the following code

```
sp_linkedservers
```

[Read more on the procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238819%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Both my @SourceDB and @TargetDB variables are correct, I had already checked my linked servers to make sure they were mapped correctly.  Thanks for the thought though.